# Deleting a record from a view in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have a view in MySQL with two tables joined together. I am using Dreamweaver to delete a record from this view, but I get an error saying:
Can not delete from join view 'SCHEMA.TABLE'

I wish to delete records from both tables. Do I have to add all the attributes from both tables into the view?

Comment: A view is just that... a "view" of the underlying data.  It's by definition read-only.  You would need to delete from the underlying tables.

Comment: Not all views can be updated/modified, especially if the underlying query is doing any data derivations. e.g. aggregate functions, `field1 + field2`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you cannot delete a record from a view, for a view is 'a view' into another table. So you would have to lookup the query / configuration that is responsible for generating the view and delete the record from the underlying table, tied to the view. In actuality this will delete the record from one table only but will accomplish what you want, the illusion of deleting the record from 'both' tables.

Comment: Well, obviously you *can* (under certain circumstances) delete from a view. It would have the same effect as deleting from the underlying table(s).

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree. However, generally speaking, a `DELETE FROM viewname WHERE id = 1` would not work, in most cases.